# How to set process variables in Script Task in JBPM 7.3

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

I have a business process defined with bpmn2 standard and I want to set up a custom object into a Script Task and pass it to a Human Task. There are three process variables:

[image: Process variables]

and here is the piece of process:

[image: Business Process]

Into Set Object there is the following code:

```
toBeApproved = new com.myteam.pocapproval.ObjectToBeApproved();
toBeApproved.setCountry(country);
toBeApproved.setAmount(amount);
```

The problem is that the process variable `toBeApproved`, after the script task, won't be filled when I start the process passing only `country` and `amount` via rest API `/server/containers/{id}/processes/{pId}/instances`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved appending this `kcontext.setVariable("toBeApproved",toBeApproved);` to the script task.